# How do (similar?) region settings trigger different NDSolve methods

Tags: differential-equations

When I solve a differential equation with `NDSolve` (MMA v11):

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],x,x],u[t,1]==0,u[t,0]==0,u[0,x]==x(1-x)},u,{t,0,.5},{x,0,1}]]
```

The outcome is fine. There are no warnings and the `Μethod` chosen is `Hermite` and `Order` is `{3,5}`.

When I set the region to what seems similar to the above and solve the same:

```
Ω = ImplicitRegion[0<=t<=0.5&&0<=x<=1.,{t,x}]

NDSolve[{D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],x,x],u[t,1]==0,u[t,0]==0,u[0,x]==x(1-x)},u,{t,x} \[Element] Ω]
```

There is a warning:

> `NDSolve::femcscd: "The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help."`

Chosen `Method` is `Unstructured` and of `Order {2,2}`.

The outcomes of both are the same, so no problem there afaik, but in this way I would not know if I have a problem with a boundary condition or a region interpretation issue when I move towards less simple region settings.

What is triggering the difference? Where are the region settings not equivalent? Can I avoid it withing explicit method setting?

Comment: somewhere in the site user21 explains that defining implicit regions changes the default method of solving to FEM, so I think you cannot avoid the explicit method setting if you wish to continue using Hermite

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to search for. You mention using `ImplicitRegion` trigers use of `FEM`, however here the method is `Unstructured`.